# Prompt for input within a loop Linux shell

Tags: linux, bash, cron

I'm creating a script to check in an interactive prompt whether to delete a cron entry or not:

```
       function cron_check()
{
    crontab -l 
    result=$?
    if [[ $result -eq 0 ]]; then
        crontab -l > crontab.out
        cat crontab.out | while read cron_entry
        do
            # ignore commented  cron entries
            [ "${cron_entry#\#}" = "$cron_entry" ] || continue # skip comment
            read -u3 -p "Do you want to remove this cron entry: $cron_entry, Please enter [Y/N]" yn
            case $yn in
                [yY] | [yY][Ee][Ss] ) sed -i "/$cron_entry/d" crontab.out;;
                [nN] | [n|N][O|o] ) break;;
                * ) echo "Please answer Y or N.";;
            esac
        done 3<&0 < crontab.out
    crontab crontab.out
    fi
}

cron_check
```

However the prompt part is not working, when running the script I'm getting: Please answer Y or N. Any help how to solve this ? 
Thank you !

Comment: Try case patterns like 'y | Y | yes | YES | Yes)'. Currently it looks like case insensitive letter followed by anything.

Comment: `sed -i '/$cron_entry/d' crontab.out` isn't going to work the way you want. The single quotes prevent the variable from being expanded. Also it might be better to write the output to a new file and copy back over when all done then to try to edit in place like this.

Comment: @EtanReisner I've edited the script, now I'l using double quotes. Good catch. Thx

Answer (score 3):

To be able to use read in your case, you need something like this using a special *file descriptor* :

```
while read crontab_entry; do   ...
   read -u3 -p 'question' yn
   ...
done 3<&0 < crontab.out
```

because STDIN is already fed by the crontab output

Comment: thx for the quick answer. 
However, I edited the script (updated my question) and it didn't work. 
when running the script I'm receiving only the content of my crontab and then Please answer Y or N. Without allowing the user to enter anything.

Answer (score 0):

I used a special file descriptor for the cat command instead and done some modifications to the sed command to work correctly.

```
function cron_check()
{
    crontab -l 
    result=$?
    if [[ $result -eq 0 ]]; then
        crontab -l > crontab.out
        exec 3< crontab.out
        while read -u 3 cron_entry
        do
            # ignore commented  cron entries
            [ "${cron_entry#\#}" = "$cron_entry" ] || continue # skip comment
            read -p "Do you want to remove this cron entry: $cron_entry, Please enter [Y/N]" yn
            case $yn in
                [yY] | [yY][Ee][Ss] ) cron_entry_esc=$(sed 's/[\*\.&/]/\\&/g' <<<"$cron_entry");crontab -l | sed "/$cron_entry_esc/d" | crontab -;;
                [nN] | [n|N][O|o] ) continue;;
                * ) echo "Please answer Y or N.";;
            esac
        done
    fi
}

cron_check
```